# Не работает answer_callback_query

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть хендлер который обрабатывает нажатия по инлайновой кнопке:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    print(call.message.chat.id)
    print(call.data)
    if call.message:
        data = call.data
        data = data.split(" ")
        id = data[0]
        vote = data[1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT voted FROM petition_void WHERE id="+str(id))
        voted = cursor.fetchone()
        print(voted)
        if voted[0] is None:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE petition_void SET voted='"+str(call.message.chat.id)+" 1' WHERE id="+str(id))
            if vote == "yes":
                cursor.execute("SELECT yes FROM petition_void WHERE id="+str(id))
                count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
                cursor.execute("UPDATE petition_void SET yes="+str(int(count) + 1)+" WHERE id="+str(id))
            if vote == "no":
                cursor.execute("SELECT no FROM petition_void WHERE id="+str(id))
                count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
                cursor.execute("UPDATE petition_void SET no="+str(int(count) + 1)+" WHERE id="+str(id))
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.message.chat.id, show_alert=True, text="Success")
```

Сам хендлер обрабатывает всё нормально, но когда я хочу ответить алертом, телеграмм возвращает:

```
Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пофиксил.

```
callback_query_id=call.message.chat.id
```

меняем на

```
callback_query_id=call.id
```

и идем читать документацию.